# Thermostatic Shower doesn't give cold showers? Normal?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I have recently purchased a home with a Thermostatic shower and when at the coldest setting the water was hot. I did some researched and changed the temperature cartridge and now the water is warm. if I turn off the hot-water then I get 100% cold water (so I know the water is flowing and it connected to the right place).

My question - when I turn to coldest setting I was expecting 100% cold water (like on every other shower I ever had), but the guy at the store is telling me that with a thermostatic shower you cannot have a "cold shower", only warm ...

Does this make any sense?
Thanks,

Comment: Any chance that the cold and hot inputs have been reversed?

Comment: Ours runs warm until the combi-boiler gets going, then cold when the hot is hot enough to effect the thermostat in the shower. What happens if you run it hot then turn it down?

Comment: @BMitch Nope (hot left, cold right), and I can open/close the valves and they react correctly

Comment: @PeteKirkham mine goes from warm to hot - I am looking for 100% cold (no hot water - freezing cold shower). Is that even possible with this unit?

Comment: Do you know the make/model?

Comment: I had this same question and found yours. I just off the phone with Dornbracht, who makes our thermostatic shower. They said that because of the design of thermostatic showers they are always going to have to mix a little bit of hot (or vice versa) so you will never get pure cold like a non thermostatic. Does that make sense to all of you? (I asked them if that was a "good thing" they said it was the price of having the thermostatic controls which prevent sudden temperature drops etc Thoughts?